# cannot get id from IEmote

Tags: c#, discord.net

Hello lately I've been trying to recreate emojis using IEmote.
I know it's in the form of <:emoji_name:emoji_id> but i can't quite find how to get the ID.
I tried to look at the [documentation of IEmote](https://discord.foxbot.me/docs/api/Discord.IEmote.html) but unfortunately i didn't find anything concerning names or ID.

Is there anyway to get the ID to generate the emote?
Thanks for the help!

Code:

```
            foreach ( var emote in emoteList)
            {
                footer += $":{emote.Key.Name}:x{emote.Value.ReactionCount} ";
                Console.WriteLine(emote);
            }
```

Comment: https://discord.foxbot.me/docs/api/Discord.Emote.html#properties

Comment: i've seen that Emote implemented it beforehand but if i try to do it then it returns me [an error.](https://i.gyazo.com/f8b6143d4d880fa14e89f31568f6f33b.png)

Comment: you are trying to cast a keyvalue pair to an `Emote`. Your `emote.Key` is the actual `IEmote`

Comment: Update: [i found a way to convert it to Emote](https://i.gyazo.com/7150e06c2c68ad33786343598e9e52fe.png)
Unfortunately it returns [this error](https://i.gyazo.com/fa77f7447112d9a7cc8ac234a8e27418.png)
In all honesty i don't quite get the difference between Emote, IEmote  and Emoji.

Comment: Emoji is the standard emoticons, while Emote is a custom guild emote...IEmote is the shared interface. That error means you are trying to cast a standard emoji to a custom emote. https://discord.foxbot.me/latest/faq/basics/basic-operations.html?tabs=emoji-others#how-do-i-add-reactions-to-a-message

Comment: So i need to make a else if based on whether or not the emote is an emoji or not?

Comment: either that or just use the IEmote itself....not sure what you're trying to do but one of those options should work.

Comment: Thank you! i just had to use emote.Key directly and it worked!
Though there is [some issues](https://i.gyazo.com/049a21944b9a9124b8055098eca162b3.png) unrelated to that it seems with embed being unable to display emojis et some basic emoji not being properly displayed. (like the anatomical heart)

Comment: Yeah, don't think you can do anything about that. Might work better in a field value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out i need to use Directly emote.Key

As for getting the ID IF it's a custom emoji
I could convert it into an Emote and therefore find the function that contains the id.